# Elastalert in kibana console

Tags: kibana, elastalert

How to get link for elastalert in kibana console, I had installed elastalert in the machine with kibana and it is running fine. However not sure on how to get it displayed in the menu bar.

[My Kibana Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4dQN.png)

Comment: are you using official ElastAlert or bitsensor fork of ElastAlert?

Answer (score 0):

The official Elastalert doesn't have any Kibana plugin. However, the folks at Bitsensor have developed their own fork of Elastalert that runs a server (running on port 3030) that exposes REST API's for manipulating rules and alerts and for that they have developed a Kibana Plugin. So, to use the Kibana plugin you should use their fork.

Relevant Links:

[Bitsensor Elastalert](https://github.com/bitsensor/elastalert)

[Kibana Plugin for Bitsensor Elastalert](https://github.com/bitsensor/elastalert-kibana-plugin)